# I would like to display one of the 30 images

Tags: flutter

I would like to display one of the 30 images in a wheel so I used the precacheImage
but when I spin my wheel the animation is crazy
Could you tell me why?
Thanks for your help

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    for(int i=0;i<31;i++) {
      tableRoue.add(Image.asset("assets/$i.png", scale: 1.5));
    }
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    for(int i=0;i<31;i++) {
      precacheImage(tableRoue[i].image, context);
    }
  }
```

Comment: How are you even getting the `i` inside `precacheImage(tableRoue[i].image, context)` ?

Comment: Sorry I modified each times and I forget to give you a good code I update now it"s the same problem maybe it's because I have big images?

Comment: I resize my 30 images 50% its ok now do you know the limite of precacheImage?

Comment: Yes, size can definitely be a problem. Is it solved then ?